# How do i change the configuration of buttons made in a for loop? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to update a buttons color to a hex code saved in an array when clicked, but i have used a for loop to create a grid of buttons so when changing the color of the button saved in variable "button" using button.config(bg="#ffffff") it will only change the color of the last made button (bottom right of the grid). How would i change the buttons color of the one that was pressed without destroying the window? Relevant code below.

```py
#activates on button press

def on_button_click(columnIndex, gameList, button, playerTurn):
    
    for i in range(row - 1, -1, -1):
        if gameList[i][columnIndex] == "":
            gameList[i][columnIndex] = playerList[playerTurn][1]
            button.config(bg=playerList[playerTurn][2])
            print("counterMatrix")
            printList(gameList)
            count_to_color(row, column)
            break
    # change player counter type
    playerTurn += 1
    # resets to p1 counter
    if playerTurn == playerCount:
        playerTurn -= playerCount

def create_grid(rows, columns, playerTurn):
    # Create the tkinter window

    window = tk.Tk()

    window.title("Connectron Grid")
    window.geometry(f"{columns * 35}x{rows * 35}")

    # Configure rows and columns to have weight
    for rowIndex in range(rows):
        window.rowconfigure(rowIndex, weight=1)

    for columnIndex in range(columns):
        window.columnconfigure(columnIndex, weight=1)

    # Create buttons for each cell in the grid
    for rowIndex in range(0, rows):
        for columnIndex in range(0, columns):
            # Create a button widget
            button = tk.Button(window, bg=colorList[rowIndex][columnIndex],command=lambda columnIndex=columnIndex: on_button_click(columnIndex, gameList, button, playerTurn)                                                             
            button.grid(row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex, sticky="nsew")

    # Run the tkinter event loop
    window.mainloop()
```

I previously have used a method of destroying the window and remaking the grid for each move but that can prove inefficient and takes up a lot of time. I would like to update the button colors when clicked without destroying the window but i have no idea how to if i've made the buttons with a for loop.

Comment: Typo error on line 39 missing brace bracket at the end. `playerTurn)` should be `playerTurn))`

Comment: line 39, in create_grid
    button = tk.Button(window, bg=colorList[rowIndex][columnIndex],command=lambda columnIndex=columnIndex: on_button_click(columnIndex, gameList, button, playerTurn))
NameError: name 'colorList' is not defined

Comment: What is this? `bg=colorList[rowIndex][columnIndex]`

Comment: @toyotaSupra I've only uploaded part of the code here, the playerTurn) is a typo from copying it here as it wasn't formatting correctly, and colorList is a nested list of size determined by the grid containing the colors that that cell should be

Comment: @toyotaSupra so for example, a grid of size 3x3 would make the colorList contain [[#ffffff , #ffffff , #ffffff] , ... ]